# Test if events are bound to backbone.js view?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm writing unit tests on a backbone.js view and I'm trying to test whether the events are set properly. Is there a way I can do this?

I'm also using jQuery so I've tried $(view.el).data().events but nothing is bound there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you can use jquery to test to see if an event is wired up by looking at the events key in the data object like so:

```
$('#yourElementToTest').data('events')
```

This all will work, if and only if the view has been attached to the dom.

Hope this helps,
MatthewJ

---

Update: In jQuery 1.8 the API for this has changed to:

`$._data(element, "events")`

See this [issue](https://github.com/IanLunn/Sequence/issues/118#issuecomment-9127308)